# Type of the source attribute for video in HTML 5

Tags: html

I just have a quick question. I'm experimenting with the video tag in HTML5 and there is something that I can;t quite understand.
First let me say that the video plays fine, tested FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari and it works just fine, but when I try to validate the page with the HTML5 validator, it throws an error.
I use the validator as a guideline, just to check for errors and help me write better code.
This is the error I get:

```
Bad value video/webm; codecs='vp8, vorbis' for attribute type on element source: Expected a token character, whitespace or a semicolon but saw , instead.
src="../video/test.webm" type="video/webm; codecs='vp8, vorbis'" />
```

And I get this error for each type of video format I'm using.
However, while reading on this page, [4.8.6 The video element — HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#the-source-element) , it seems that I'm doing things right.
Like I said I don't rely on the validator other than to help me see errors in my code, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something here, or is it because the validator is still experimental.
Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your type from this:

```
type="video/webm; codecs='vp8, vorbis'"
```

to this

```
type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'
```

EDIT

While checking the HTML5 spec for the [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#the-source-element) element, the way I state above is how it is defined in the spec. If you are still getting validation errors I would assume it is a bug with the validator.  I'd submit a bug report [here](http://validator.w3.org/feedback.html) so that it will get fixed.

Comment: @jnkrois - which validator are you using?

Comment: @amurra - http://validator.w3.org/ and select the option for HTML5 from the dropdown list

Comment: @jnkrois - looks like a bug in the validator since you are conforming to the current HTML5 draft anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I was not doing something wrong without noticing.

Comment: @jnkrois - I think you are doing something wrong, and amurra's answer should have fixed it. My tests with the validator confirm this. The document you link to says that the type attribute must be a valid mime type according to RFC 2616. Following the ABNF production of that, the codecs part matches "parameter" and the mutiple values within must be a "quoted-string". In RFC 2616, a quoted-string is delimited by double quotes only. There is no single quotes option. So the validator is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<source type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' src="media/video.webm" />
```

You can use single quotes for the `type` attribute and the double quotes for the `codecs` value.
This is valid and it doesn't harm your document.